# How to transfer a photo via Android WebView to a jQuery script?

Tags: java, android, jquery, kotlin

I want to use **Photo Picker** in my Android project. Content is displayed via WebView. I need to select an image from the device's memory and pass it to a jQuery script for pre-cropping. **I need to transfer the selected image to webview**. Thank you.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), photo -> {
    if (photo == null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image: "+ photo , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

And processing the HTML button:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick() {
            pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                    .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
                    .build());
        }
    }, "ok");
```

Comment: Think that you want to transfer a photo uri to that script. Not a bitmap or the content of the image file. Please explain yourself better.

Comment: Create an image file and send it to jquery for cropping and sending to the server.
I already have the trimming and sending scripts ready.
You need to do something like this: https://gist.github.com/mksantoki/097bb1fa73af1f404acc02bb594cd743 but using Photo Picker

Comment: A photo picker picks an existing file. For which you get an uri. Unclear what file you wanna create yet.

Comment: I need to transfer the selected image to webview